# How to change multiple fe_user passwords in TYPO3 6.2?

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-6.2.x

I want to reset the password for 46 fe_users, but when I just update the field "password" I can see the actual password in the columns instead some encoded value...
`UPDATE "fe_users" SET PASSWORD="test" WHERE pid=53`
I want it to look like the entry above "test".
[image: password]
It makes sense to me that my approach doesn't work but I can't figure out what else I could try...anyone an idea? In the backend records page I only know how to change a password one by one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use BE-modul Scheduler (install EXT:scheduler if not already installed).
Select Class `Convert user passwords to salted hashes` and run this task, once.

Description from this task: *Update all frontend and backend user passwords to salted hashes. This task deactivates itself when completed.*

Comment: Not sure if it works with plain passwords, but should with md5() hashed.

Comment: In TYPO3 6.2 EXT:saltedpasswords BulkUpdateTask checks for plain and md5 hashed passwords befor converting, and prefix with M or C. Citat:
Passwords prefixed with M or C might be salted passwords:
M means: originally a md5 hash before it was salted (eg. default be_users).
C means: originally a cleartext password with lower hash looping count generated by t3sec_saltedpw.
Both M and C will be updated to usual salted hashes on first login of user.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that without any DB hacking. In the List Module you can edit just one field per record of but from many records at the same time. e.g. edit all Name fields or in your case all password fields.

With hundreds of records your of course faster with hacking db + scheduler. But with just 46 I would maybe try the following:

- List Module
- Go to the sysfolder that is holding your fe_users
- Click on the text `Website User (46)` the page reloads now
- Scroll down and tick the checkbox `password`
- Confirm with `set fields` the page reloads
- Now scroll up again to the head of the `Website User` table and click on the icon beside `password` the page reloads again
- now you can tab -> paste -> tab -> paste the passwords of all users really fast and save at once.

Even if you don't want to do it this way, its always good to in mind that it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the passwords by chaning the password in the database the password is encrypted after the next login of each user.

if you want to encrypt the passwords after changing you can use the sheduler task to encrypt your passwords like @jokumer wrote.